# Python coding style

Tags: python

I have two code snippets which essentially do the same thing. Here are the two samples :

```
retval = count or num_element > 0
```

and

```
if count or num_element > 0 :
    retval = True
else:
    retval = False
```

Is there any specific reason the first option is preferred over the second? I know that people have their own choices. But I am curious to know if there are any performance or other implications. I feel second way is more readable.

Comment: I would argue that 2nd case is *way* more readable. It's just an opinion, but yes it is, but I find it made idiot-readable. I think anyone who can read the language should have no big problems with the 1st code. With the 1st form you get 4 to 1 compression in lines of code, and in case of more than 2-3 such tests in a row, I would rather like to read 5 lines of 1st example than 20 lines of if-elses. Maybe that was it, also it's less typing =).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are **not** essentially the same. If `count` is a true value (non-zero, or not an empty container, etc.) then the *value of `count` is assigned* in the first form. The second form always assigns a boolean.

Unless the statement is part of a tight high-iteration-count loop, performance shouldn't be an issue. Even if it *is* part of a loop, the difference will be minute.

What remains is a stylistic choice, but your second form is *usually* extremely redundant.

Whenever I see a `if test: value = True`, `else: value = False` statement, it is usually a sign that someone hasn't understood that the *test itself* is already returning a boolean or can be made into one.

If you need a true boolean value, use:

```
retval = bool(count) or num_element > 0
```

otherwise just stick with the first option.

Comment: @Martjin: My bad. I have not posted my question correctly. I have edited it. However, your answer was spot on for my incomplete question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be neater to say `retval = bool(count or num_element > 0)`?

Comment: @kqr: only if `num_element` is a custom class that returns something other than a boolean from the `__gt__` method would it a make difference here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understand it wouldn't make a difference in most cases, I'm just suggesting it as an improvement – in part due to what you're saying and in part because it follows the general pattern also represented in things like `stuff = set([1, 2, 3] * 4)` where the entire RHS is wrapped.

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically wanted `retval` to wind up as either `True` or `False` (rather than possibly the value of `count` if that value is truthy), you could do the following:

```
retval = True if count else num_element > 0
```

Comment: I could be wrong here but if count were to be a false value then retval would also be false, no matter what num_element was.

Comment: I misremembered the original expression and thought it was an `and`. Fixed now.